# Linux terminal for virutalization purposes, no X windows

Tags: linux, virtualbox, unix, gui, x-windows

I was wondering if I could download a linux distro somewhere that just featured the terminal with no GUI. Would this be possible in a Ubuntu liveCD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are valid reasons to want a CLI only live-cd operating system, but if your goal is merely to be able to use the CLI instead of the GUI then a much simpler work-around would be just to use the default Ubuntu Desktop live-cd, and switch from GUI to the CLI using your Fkeys.

[image]

1. Boot up an Ubuntu Desktop live-cd (don't use the server version as it has limited functionality; just BusyBox.)

[image]

2. When you reach the Try or Install screen press CONTROL+ALT+F1, and you will be switched into TTY1 (the CLI interface).

[image]

3. You're already logged in as username "ubuntu" with no password required. You can run/do whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special edition of Ubuntu just for this. It is called [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/server). Oh and BTW, this edition runs awesome in a VM. Loads really quick and runs very fast compared to the desktop distros (or any other OS for that matter).

There is no limited functionality. If you want to you can install anything you want later; it uses the same repositories as the other distros.

Some more tips on doing this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_as_Guest_OS